# How to disable .ms-acal-title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, hyperlink

I am trying to disable the title in each calendar event. Currently when a user clicks on the event title they are taken to the display page, not the display pop up but an entirely new URL. I want the user to only be able to access the edit pop up form no matter where they click on the event. 
[image: Example of calendar events]
In this example the title I am referencing is Non Working. The best I've managed to do is instead of redirecting to a new page refresh the parent which reloads the calendar. I have tried to disable `.ms-acal-title` using jQuery but with no luck.

This code opens the edit form instead of the display form when the user clicks on the `.ms-acal-item` which is exactly what I want however, the same approach does not work for the `.ms-acal-title`.

```
$("body").on("dblclick click", ".ms-acal-item", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 

    //extract default Event page url and generate new one
    var defaultEventPageUrl = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var newEventPageUrl = defaultEventPageUrl.replace('DispEvent.aspx','EditEvent.aspx');

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title:"Edit Event",url:newEventPageUrl}); 
});
```

This code refreshes the parent instead of opening the display page. As you can see I have tried `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` but this does not prevent the display page from opening.

```
$("td.ms-acal-title a").attr('disabled', true); 
$("body").on("dblclick click", "ms-acal-sdiv .ms-acal-title a, .ms-acal-ddiv .ms-acal-title a", function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation(); 
    parent.window.location.href=parent.window.location.href;
    return false;
});
```

I tried to use the below code to ban the url and open the edit form but this approach was also unsuccessful.

```
function disable(){
    var good_links = new Array();
    good_links[0] = "www.google.com";
    links=document.getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        if (!inArray(links[i].href, good_links)) {
            links[i].href="#";
            //links[i].href="javascript:return false";
        }
    }
}

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

window.onload=disable;
```

I suspect that I am looking at the wrong element and `.ms-acal-title` may not be the item which is firing the redirect to the display page.

Any guidance on the correct item to disable or how to stop `.ms-acal-title` acting as a hyperlink would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified your first script to *override handler once event link is clicked*:

```
  $(".ms-acal-item a").removeAttr("onclick"); //remove original EditLink2 handler
$(document).on('click dblclick','.ms-acal-item a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //extract default Event page url and generate new one
    var defaultEventPageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var newEventPageUrl = defaultEventPageUrl.replace('DispEvent.aspx','EditEvent.aspx');
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title:"Edit Event",url:newEventPageUrl}); 
});
```